# How to use const auto & in eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, eclipse-cdt, auto

I am tryin to define a function inside Eclipse Luna CDT file

using auto keyword. When I am putting the auto keyword inside header file in the definition I am getting a warning:

```
‘getContent’ function uses ‘auto’ type specifier without trailing return type [enabled by default]
```

In the CPP file I am getting a CODAN error for this code:

```
const vector<unique_ptr<Object>> & Holder::getContent()const{
    return Holder::objects ;

}
```

The error is:  Member declaration not found.

Have I done something wrong? c++11 is already activated in the eclipse and I am using smart pointers and auto without problem in other places (inside a for each loop as below)

```
for (auto talk : conversation) {
        result.push_back(talk.first);
}
```

Comment: `auto` as a return type placeholder (*without* a trailing return type) is a C++14 feature, and also, IIRC, when used in a declaration, the defitnition should use a placeholder as well, and must be visible to all translation units that refer to it

Comment: Show the _declaration_ of the `getContent` function.